# Gunicorn is throwing Out of Memory with max request and max requests jitter

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord

### Gunicorn is throwing Out of Memory

I have tried to add max request and max requests jitter but still getting Out of Memory. Gunicorn is being controlled by supervisor

`exec gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --bind unix:/webapps/run/myproject/gunicorn.sock --max-requests 500 --max-requests-jitter 50 --workers 3 --timeout 300 --user=root --group=webapps`

I have tried to check the gunicorn process ID it consumes 95% of memory out of 20GB and started 18 hours ago
what I am doing wrong. Any help appreciated

Comment: A timeout of 300 seems excessive when the default is 30, any reason for that? What is your app doing to consume so much memory anyway?

Comment: When I upload a file with many users it takes time thats why I use 300 to avoid time out error, application is school management system.

Comment: How big are the files and how long do they take to upload? How many simultaneous requests are you handling (per second/minute)?

Comment: A file with 100 record student ID and marks takes 1.5 min but I don't think this is the problem when I started server it works well but after some time like 5 hours it started to consume more memory

Comment: 1.5 minutes is a pretty significant especially since you only have 3 workers. Tuning the settings to find the sweet spot is a continual process but I would try the following - increase the number of workers to 10 (`2 * num_cpu_cores + 1` is the recommended starting point) and reduce max-requests significantly because if your requests are taking that long then they won't be restarting that much at the moment (worst case 500 requests * 1.5 minutes = 12.5 hours)